# iOS 9/Swift 2 IPA size has increased on the App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, ios9, ipa

After upgrading the app to iOS 9/Swift 2, I have noticed that the IPA size has increased from 18 mb (Swift 1.2/ iOS 8) to 26 mb. Please note that I have disabled Bitcode because some frameworks are not supporting it. I also noticed that libswiftCore.dylib size has increased from 6mb to 14 mb. Is there a way to determine why the size has increased? If so, how can I reflect this change on the app store?

Comment: Try some simple math. Your IPA increased by 8MB (26-18), and the swift runtime increased by 8MB (14 - 6). Coincidence?

Comment: The doubling of the dylib is probably just because of added architecture(s). If you were using app thinning, the unneeded architecture(s) could be sliced out when installing onto a device.

Comment: Are you saying that if I enable bitcode, it will reduce the IPA size?

Answer (score 0):

You state that the IPA size went up from 18 to 26 and you also noticed that the size of the swiftCore.dylib increased from 6-14

so you already have determined why the size increased :)
it isn't you, it is apple proprietrary / internal to the runtime